# How start app in express js (nodejs)? TypeError:app.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How start app in express js (nodejs)? TypeError:app.set is not a function.
Console.log screen

[image: screen]

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;
});
```

Comment: Where is the `app.set` line in your code?

Comment: @skypjack, app.set only in bin/www file (default file). `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000'); app.set('port', port);`

Answer (score 4):

Solved a problem:
1. add module.exports = app;

Comment: I already have that line in my code, but still the error. Any idea how to solve it ??